# Frame changes when "applicationDidBecomeActive"

Tags: objective-c

I have a little message that appears when the app is conecting to the server.
It works nice when the app is launching, and also the rest of the time that the app needs to show this message, but if I sleep the app, I put it on the background and then I wake it up, the message appears again but the whole frame moves up, see screenshots.
The first one is right after launching, that message on the bottom appears and it dissapears correctly, and the view is back to what is used to be, perfect.

[image]

But the second screenshot is the result of making the app going to background, and then waking it up, on the "`applicationDidBecomeActive`" I have a method that requires conection to the server and therefore the small view must appear. The problem is that the window or the `navigation controller` moves up behind the status bar. And leaves that white space

[image: app from launch]

Heres the code that I use to make shorter the navigation view and add that message view and make it longer again.

```
- (void)addMessageView:(NSString *)message{
UIWindow *window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
if(![window viewWithTag:3]){//Si no hay un messageView no lo meto.
    [window addSubview:messageView];
    CGRect frameWindow = window.frame;
    int heightMessage = 50;
    messageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, frameWindow.size.height, 320, heightMessage);



    UINavigationController *nav = window.rootViewController;


    //Pillo el UILabel y lo seteo
    UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[messageView viewWithTag:1];
    label.text = message;
    CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(296,9999);
    CGSize sizeMsg = [label.text sizeWithFont:label.font constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize lineBreakMode:label.lineBreakMode];
    UIActivityIndicatorView *activity = (UIActivityIndicatorView *)[messageView viewWithTag:2];
    int xLabel = (320 - (sizeMsg.width + activity.frame.size.width + 5))/2;

    CGRect frameActivity = activity.frame;
    activity.frame = CGRectMake(xLabel, 13, frameActivity.size.width, frameActivity.size.height);
    label.frame = CGRectMake(xLabel + activity.frame.size.width + 5, 15, sizeMsg.width, sizeMsg.height);


    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];


    nav.view.frame = CGRectMake(frameWindow.origin.x, frameWindow.origin.y, frameWindow.size.width, frameWindow.size.height - heightMessage);
    messageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, frameWindow.size.height - heightMessage, 320, heightMessage);

    [UIView commitAnimations];

}
}
```

AND also to put it back to the previous position:
     - (void)hideMessageView{

```
UIWindow *window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
UINavigationController *nav = window.rootViewController;
CGRect frameWindow = window.frame;
if([window viewWithTag:3]){//Si no hay un messageView no lo meto.
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                     animations:^{
                         nav.view.frame = CGRectMake(frameWindow.origin.x, frameWindow.origin.y, frameWindow.size.width, frameWindow.size.height);
                         messageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, frameWindow.size.height +5 , 320, 0);
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         [messageView removeFromSuperview];

                     }];
}
NSLog(@"Tam Window: %@ y nav %@", frameWindow, nav.view.frame);
}
```

Let me know what do you think.

Comment: Actually no, I tried several things but I wasnt able to figure out why  it did that

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling ***Autolayout***, I had the same issue with my UI.